# https and http combined .htaccess (different issue)

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, ssl, https, woocommerce

OK. Hopefully someone can help me with a suggestion-

1. I have a WordPress multisite using subfolders
2. I am using WooCommerce
3. I have a std Ubuntu 12.04/LAMP server with a GoDaddy Certificate installed

If it turn on SSL, it affects my entire domain (obviously) so my primary site ends up as:
'https://main-sitename.com'

My multisite blogs also come up as:
`https://main-sitename.com/blogname-1`
`https://main-sitename.com/blogname-2`

and so on. ALL of my menu links are also https which disables outside links because the urls all get prepended with https. :-/

What I am trying to do is get this:

`http://main-sitename.com`
`http://main-sitename.com/blogname-1`
`http://main-sitename.com/blogname-2`

`https://main-sitename.com/shop/` (WooCommerce will force HTTPS on checkout and then un-enforce it when done).

- So, Anyone have any ideas on how I can remedy this? On an interesting note, when I had the EXACT same site on Rackspace Cloud Sites everything worked fine. When I moved to a self managed Cloudserver this happened. Is there something I missed?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like SSLRequireSSL has been set for the entire server. Since you only want to enforce HTTPS on /shop/ directory. Add a .htaccess file in that directory that contains:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

This will force anyone connecting to your shop with http:// to be redirected to the same URI, but on https://

**EDIT 2**

This works for me (with www.myserver.com changed to my real server name). I'm using date and name permalinks in WP. As soon as I go to http://www.myserver.com/shop/ I'm redirected to https. It preserves the URI.

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
# Addition to force redirect to https when they visit the shop!
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on
RewriteRule (shop/.*$) https://www.myserver.com/$1 [R=301,L]
# Back to WordPress changes
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Comment: Thanks Erik. Seems like it would work except WordPress makes the /subdirs on the fly. There is no actual folder as it is generated dynamically. htaccess WILL rewrite the URLs however. Is there anything I can put in the htaccess file my base wordpress folder (this is the htaccess that wordpress adheres to) that will force my urls to be rewritten as http (not https) and just let the shop url be https? (hope that question makes sense)

Comment: You should be able to do essentially the same thing in your base .htaccess. Leave the RewriteCond alone. The RewriteRule will need to change. Let me edit and see if I can get the rule as close as possible.

Comment: Any suggestions you can give me would be greatly appreciated. Thanks Erik

Comment: I'll see if I can't manage to get some time tomorrow to re-install my subdomain that has WordPress and see what is going on.